# An innocent homomorphism between groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

There does not exist a nontrivial homomorphism $h:(\mathbb{Z}_8,+)\rightarrow(\mathbb{Z}_3,+)$.  I am trying to understand this well-known fact.

Let $h(x) = x$.  Then certainly $h(a+b) = h(a) + h(b)$.  Since $h$ has this property (the defining property of a group homomorphism) why is $h$ not a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}_8,+)$ to $(\mathbb{Z}_3$,+)?

For example, $$h(2+5)=h(7) = 7 \equiv 1\,(\mathrm{mod}\,3)$$ or differently

$$h(2+5)=h(2) + h(5) = 2 + 5 = 7 \equiv 1\,(\mathrm{mod}\,3)$$

Where, then, is the problem?

Comment: $h(1) + h(7) = 1+1$, but $1+7 = 8 \equiv 0 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: What does $h(x) = x$ mean? The element $x$ lies inside $\mathbb{Z}_8$ not $\mathbb{Z}_3$...these groups have different elements.

Comment: Apologies fretty.  Using T. Bonger's notation, $h(k + 8 \Bbb{Z}) = k + 3 \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by $h(x) = x$, since $\Bbb{Z}_8$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$ are 
different sets. Perhaps you mean

$$h(k + 8 \Bbb{Z}) = k + 3 \Bbb{Z}$$

However, this will fail to be well defined: Try considering $k = 0$ and $k = 8$:

Note that $0 + 8 \Bbb{Z} = 8 + 8 \Bbb{Z}$, but we have

$$h(0 + 8 \Bbb{Z}) = 0 + 3 \Bbb{Z} \neq 2 + 3 \Bbb{Z} = h(8 + 3 \Bbb{Z})$$

Hence, this is not actually a function.

An easier way to proceed is via the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_isomorphism_theorem). This states that if $h$ is a homomorphism,

$$\mathbb{Z}_8 / \ker h \cong \text{im } h \leq \mathbb{Z}_3$$

Hence, $\mathbb{Z}_8 / \ker h$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a group of order $3$, and so by Lagrange's Theorem must have size $1$ (in which case $8$ is trivial) or size $3$. The second case is not possible since

$$\left|\mathbb{Z}_8 / \ker h\right| = \frac{8}{|\ker h|}$$

is a divisor of $8$.

Comment: You have correctly interpreted my function "$h(x)=x$".  Can you elaborate on "this will fail to be well defined"?  I am wondering what it is about $h$ that does not abide with $h(a+b) = h(a) + h(b)$.

Comment: @Doubt The problem is that if we use different names for the inputs, we get fundamentally different outputs. Hence, it's not actually even a well-defined function. I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, as was stated in the comments, the problem with the $h$ in the question is that it's not well defined.

We have $8\equiv 0$ mod $8$, but

$h(8)=8\equiv 2$ mod $3$

while

$h(0) \equiv 0$ mod $3$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your map $h$ is when the argument "wraps" modulo 8. My interpretation of your definition is $h(x + 8\mathbb Z) = x + 3\mathbb Z$ for $x\in\{0,\ldots,7\}$. Then
$$
h(0) = 0 \mod 3
$$
but
$$
h(4) + h(4) = 4 + 4 \equiv 1 + 1 = 2\mod 3.
$$
Because of $0 = 4 + 4$, this contradict the homomorphism property.

---

Why is there no homomorphism $\mathbb Z_8 \to \mathbb Z_3$ but the trivial one?
In general, if $G$ and $H$ are finite groups and $f : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then the order of $\operatorname{im} f$ is a divisor of the order of $G$ as well as the order of $H$ (follows from Lagrange and the homomorphism theorem).

In your case, we get  $\lvert \operatorname{im} h\rvert$ divides $\gcd(8,3) = 1$.
So $\operatorname{im} h = \{0\}$ and $h$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can be a little more general if you use the first isomorphism theorem. Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups and assume that there exists a $\phi:G\rightarrow H$. Then by first isomorphism theorem $G/Ker(\phi)\cong Im(\phi)$. The image is a subgroup of $H$. Also $|Im(\phi)|$ must divide the order of $G$. So if we apply to this setting.

So if we apply this idea to this setting. There are no subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ whose order divides $8$ except $\{0\}$.